# iptables: prohibit access to interface by GID unless it is local network

Tags: iptables

I have the following rule to prohibit use of interface for users outside of `fullnetwork` group.

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -o eth+  -m owner \! --gid-owner fullnetwork -j REJECT
```

How can I allow local networks for users outside of `fullnetwork`?

I've tried this, but it didn't work

```
ipset create local hash:net
ipset add local 192.168.0.0/16
ipset add local 172.16.0.0/16
ipset add local 10.0.0.0/8
iptables -I OUTPUT -o eth+  -m owner \! --gid-owner fullnetwork -j REJECT
iptables -I OUTPUT -o eth+  -m owner \! --gid-owner fullnetwork -m set --match-set local src -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: If outside of fullnetwork, and not match better I think, just one line. 'iptables -I OUTPUT -o eth+  -m owner \! --gid-owner fullnetwork  -m  set ! --match-set local src -j REJECT'

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: What does it mean, didn't work? You have an accept line too, isn't it?

Comment: Note that my answer was made after the "that didn't work" comment.

Answer (score 1):

The required functionality has been added in [*iptables* >= 1.8.4](https://git.netfilter.org/iptables/commit/?id=a08595b2219e6fbd848f07d9bb63c8922c5d97c0) and [around kernel 5.3](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=ea6cc2fd8a2b89ab6dcd096ba6dbc1ecbdf26564) (and is not available at all in *nftables*): also matching on *supplementary* groups, rather than only the current (primary) group: [`--suppl-groups`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#suppl):

> `--suppl-groups`
>
> Causes group(s) specified with `--gid-owner` to be also checked in the
> supplementary groups of a process.

Without this option, and without using this group directly for example with `sg fullnetwork`, even this command:

> ```
> iptables -I OUTPUT -o eth+  -m owner \! --gid-owner fullnetwork -j REJECT
> ```

can't have the announced effect: it won't allow users having the group `fullnetwork` just in their supplementary group list to use network.

So to have this match as needed and reject other users, one should use for example:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -o eth+  -m owner ! --gid-owner fullnetwork --suppl-groups -j REJECT
```

To be consistent, adding exceptions to exceptions should not become an ACCEPT rule, else users part of `fullnetwork` get potentially less access rights for the local networks than users merely permitted to access some LANS, in case further restrictions are added in later rules. Instead create an user chain to organize the rules together and have them bail out from rejection with a RETURN verdict without ever using an ACCEPT verdict and end with a single REJECT verdict. Replace the two previous *iptables* rules with:

```
iptables -N reject_non_allowed_on_eth

iptables -A reject_non_allowed_on_eth -m owner --gid-owner fullnetwork --suppl-groups -j RETURN
iptables -A reject_non_allowed_on_eth -m set --match-set local dst -j RETURN
iptables -A reject_non_allowed_on_eth -j REJECT

iptables -I OUTPUT -o eth+ -j reject_non_allowed_on_eth
```

This can be read like this:

- if using an Ethernet interface,

  - if in `fullnetwork` group, bail out
  - if reaching private LANs, bail out
  - whatever is left is not authorized: reject it
- more rules could be added later to further filter the remaining packets

Please also note an other change: the match is done on the *destination* (`dst`) and not the *source* (`src`) which would have allowed to reach anything as long as the system has an address in this range. Emitting *from* this address would always have been permitted if matching on source and this doesn't appear intended.

Comment: I've tried this verbatim on Linux 6.5, and any user outside of `fullnetwork` group is able to access non-local networks nevertheless

Comment: @andreoss I made a typo in my answer for the one-liner part. Fixed (check the changed order of the parameters). If it still doesn't work, can you provide `iptables-save -c`'s output (the `-c` parameter will tell where the rules matched)?